# How to use \multirow correctly?

Tags: tables, multirow, arrays

I want to make a table like this:
[image]

With the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\heading[1]{\multicolumn1l{\textcolor{White}{\large\textbf{#1}\strut}}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\colouredRows{}% initialise empty list
\forcsvlist{\listadd\colouredRows}{ 7, 8, 9, 10}
\newcommand\SetRowColour{%
  \xifinlist{\number\rownum}\colouredRows{\cellcolor{DodgerBlue!20}}{}%
}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arrybackslash}l}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}r}

\rowcolors{2}{White}{white}% initialise the \rownum counter from xcolor
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ LL CCCC R }
      \rowcolor{MidnightBlue}
      \heading{Student} 
      & \heading{Marker} 
      & \multicolumn{4}\heading{\textcolor{White}{\large\textbf{Essay}}}
      & \heading{Total} \\
                & & Originality & Synthesis & Effort & Overall & \\
                \cmidrule(lr){3-6}
                            \multirow{2}*{James} & Alice  & 9 & 8 & 7 & 8.0 & \multirow{4}*{\textbf{7.9}}\\
                              & Amelia & 8 & 9 & 7 & 8.0 & \\
                              & Anton  & 9 & 7 & 7 & 7.7 & \\
                              & Arthur & 7 & 8 & 8 & 7.7 & \\
                              & Alice  & 9 & 9 & 7 & 8.3 & \\
                              & Amelia & 9 & 8 & 8 & 8.3 & \\
                              & Anton  & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8.0 & \\
                              & Arthur & 7 & 9 & 7 & 7.7 & \\
                              & Alice  &10 & 9 &10 & 9.7 & \\
                              & Amelia & 9 & 7 & 8 & 8.0 & \\
                              & Anton  & 9 & 8 & 8 & 8.3 & \\
                              & Arthur & 9 &10 & 9 & 9.3 & \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But the `\multirow` command makes some problems.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please start by fixing obvious typos; e.g., by changing `\aarrybackslash` to `\arraybackslash` and `\cntering` to `\centering`.

Comment: @Mico got it, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question is about how to use `\multirow` correctly, I've simplified the layout by omitting all directives related to color, font size, and font weight.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll cccc r @{}}
\toprule
  Student & Marker & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Essay} & Total \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6}
  & & Originality & Synthesis & Effort & Overall & \\
\midrule
      \multirow{4}{*}{James}  & Alice  & 9 & 8 & 7 & 8.0 & \multirow{4}{*}{7.9}\\
                              & Amelia & 8 & 9 & 7 & 8.0 & \\
                              & Anton  & 9 & 7 & 7 & 7.7 & \\
                              & Arthur & 7 & 8 & 8 & 7.7 & \\ 
      \addlinespace
      \multirow{4}{*}{Janice} & Alice  & 9 & 9 & 7 & 8.3 & \multirow{4}{*}{8.1}\\
                              & Amelia & 9 & 8 & 8 & 8.3 & \\
                              & Anton  & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8.0 & \\
                              & Arthur & 7 & 9 & 7 & 7.7 & \\ 
      \addlinespace
      \multirow{4}{*}{Julie}  & Alice  &10 & 9 &10 & 9.7 & \multirow{4}{*}{8.8}\\
                              & Amelia & 9 & 7 & 8 & 8.0 & \\
                              & Anton  & 9 & 8 & 8 & 8.3 & \\
                              & Arthur & 9 &10 & 9 & 9.3 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. :)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Edit:**
`multirow` cells should be written after coloring table rows, so it should be placed to the last color cell with negative number of spanned rows.  That table code has unified form, In MWE below all `multirow` cells are written on the same way.

In comparison to your code, the following changes are done:

- redefined is `\heading` command
- defined is command for `multicolumn` cells
- for the first four columns with numbers are used `S` column type
- for table is used `tabularx` (for evenly distributed columns with numbers, `X` column cells are employed in definition for `\mcx` command used for column headings in `S` columns)
- corrected are definitions of new column types (as you defined them have no sense)
- MWE below reproduce table as you show in image in question

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
%\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\heading{m}
    {\large\textbf{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{C}{#2}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll *{3}{S[table-format=2.0]}
                                         S[table-format=1.1] c}
    \rowcolor{MidnightBlue}
\heading{Student}
    & \heading{Marker}
        & \mcc[4]{\heading{Essay}}
            & \heading{Total}           \\
    &   & \mcx{Originality} 
            & \mcx{Synthesis} 
                & \mcx{Effort} 
                    & \mcx{Overall} & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-6}
    & Alice  & 9 & 8 & 7 & 8.0 & \\
    & Amelia & 8 & 9 & 7 & 8.0 & \\
    & Anton  & 9 & 7 & 7 & 7.7 & \\
\multirow{-3.8}{*}{James}
    & Arthur & 7 & 8 & 8 & 7.7 & \multirow{-3.8}{*}{\textbf{7.9}} \\
    \rowcolor{cyan!20}
    & Alice  & 9 & 9 & 7 & 8.3 & \\
    \rowcolor{cyan!20}
    & Amelia & 9 & 8 & 8 & 8.3 & \\
    \rowcolor{cyan!20}
    & Anton  & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8.0 & \\
    \rowcolor{cyan!20}
\multirow{-3.8}{*}{Janice}
    & Arthur & 7 & 9 & 7 & 7.7 & \multirow{-3.8}{*}{\textbf{8.1}}\\
    & Alice  &10 & 9 &10 & 9.7 & \\
    & Amelia & 9 & 7 & 8 & 8.0 & \\
    & Anton  & 9 & 8 & 8 & 8.3 & \\
\multirow{-3.8}{*}{Julie}
    & Arthur & 9 &10 & 9 & 9.3 & \multirow{-3.8}{*}{\textbf{7.9}}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Zarko, thanks for answering. Why you use -3.8 in multirow? After compilation, the page seems too long to view.

Comment: @WYW, see added explanation. -3.8 is selected after estimation that it better vertical center contents of `multirow` cells (as -4). Table is in comparison to your only wee bit wider and is a wee bit higher (for number of rows x `\extrarowheight`).

Answer (score 3):

You can construct that tabular easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

Moreover, you won't have the thin white lines you have in some PDF viewers if you use the key `table` of `xcolor` (see for example Zarko's answer).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\heading{m}
    {\large\textbf{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ll *{3}{S[table-format=2.0]}S[table-format=1.1]>{\bfseries}c}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{MidnightBlue}{1} 
  \rowcolor{cyan!20}{7-10} 
\Body
  \heading{Student} & \heading{Marker} & \Block{1-4}{\heading{Essay}} &&&& \heading{Total} \\
      &   & {Originality} & {Synthesis} & {Effort} & {Overall} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){3-6}
  \Block{4-1}{James}
      & Alice  & 9 & 8 & 7 & 8.0 & \Block{4-1}{7.9} \\
      & Amelia & 8 & 9 & 7 & 8.0 & \\
      & Anton  & 9 & 7 & 7 & 7.7 & \\
      & Arthur & 7 & 8 & 8 & 7.7 \\
  \Block{4-1}{Janice}
      & Alice  & 9 & 9 & 7 & 8.3 & \Block{4-1}{8.1}\\
      & Amelia & 9 & 8 & 8 & 8.3 \\
      & Anton  & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8.0 \\
      & Arthur & 7 & 9 & 7 & 7.7 \\
  \Block{4-1}{Julie}
      & Alice  &10 & 9 &10 & 9.7 & \Block{4-1}{7.9}\\
      & Amelia & 9 & 7 & 8 & 8.0 \\
      & Anton  & 9 & 8 & 8 & 8.3 \\
      & Arthur & 9 &10 & 9 & 9.3 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)